# How to dynamically get value attribute value of a row using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to create one table using XSLT and CSS. The table should look like

```
                ID    FNAME
                 1    AA
                 2    BB
```

XML:

```
<students>
    <studentDetails  id="1" fname="AA"/>
    <studentDetails  id="2" fname="BB"/>
</students>
```

XSLT so far:
I have traverse upto studentDetails  and then

```
<td >
      <xsl:call-template name="zz">
      <xsl:with-param name="child-name" select="'id'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
     <xsl:template name="zz">
<xsl:param name="child-name"/>

<xsl:value-of select="*[name(@id) = $child-name]"/>//should print 1 and then 2 in next row
```

Can somebody suggest where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first don't pass "'id'" just use "id"
At second = pattern * selects node, but you need attr (@*), so you need write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$child-name]"/>
```

Comment: At first don't pass "'id'" just use "id" At second = pattern * selects node----sorry didnt get u, can u pls explain a bit.

Comment: students, studentDetails  -it is elements, when you write XPath expression to code any of them you need use '*'. id, fname are attributes to get to them use over XPath over '@*' 
Instead of * or @* you can specify axes (see hacker response) attribute::* = @*

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<xsl:value-of select="attribute::*[name() = $child-name]"/>
```

instead.

**Edit:** I have just read through Dewfy's answer. This is equivalent to what he proposed. Except for his "at first" part is *an alternative* to this, not something you have to *in addition to* changing `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: whats the difference between <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$child-name]"/>
 and <xsl:value-of select="attribute::*[name() = $child-name]"/>

Comment: Wondering - none ;-) It's just that after reading the first sentence I assumed he's talking about different approach instead.